# Finding the point through which a circle passes if the general equation is given

Tags: geometry, circles

No idea how it is even possible to do this.

So we have the general equation (but the y-coordinate of the center is still kept variable as you can see below):-
$$x^2+y^2-2x-3ky-2=0$$

We have to find through which two fixed points does the circle pass.

Comment: You can substitute 2 values for k and then solve for x and y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completing the squares you see that the circles are of the form
$$ (x-1)^2 + (y-\frac{3}{2}k)^2 = 3 + \frac{9}{4}k^2$$
So we have a family of circles with center $(1,\frac{3}{2}k)$ and radius $\sqrt{3 + \frac{9}{4}k^2}$ By symmetry, if the circles have exactly two points in common, this has to happen for $y=0$.

In fact, you will find exactly two values of $x$ wich solve the equation you get if $y=0$. I won't show you, though, why these are the only solutions...

Comment: why do the circles have two points in common only happen for $y=0$

Comment: As I said, because of symmetry (compare $k$ and $-k$), if there are in fact only two solutions, this has to happen in the center of symmetry ($y=0$). The fact that it only happens for $y=0$ I did not prove and, as I also said, leave this to you. Hint: one of the other answers contains the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If the points $(x, y)$ of interest satisfy the equation for distinct parameter values $k$ and $k'$, then subtracting the two equations gives that $(x, y)$ must satisfy $$3ky' - 3ky = 0.$$

Answer (score -1):

Hint: at which points does your circle meet the axes?

Comment: @MiceElf I'm not critiquing nor requesting clarification, just trying to suggest that substituting $y=0$ (x-axis equation) into the circle equation, the parameter disappears so the intersection points do not depend on it.

Comment: @Aretino Agree with your approach. In addition, one has to check whether the resultant quadratic equation has real roots or not.